# Swift 3: Caching images in a collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm currently working through my app, updating it to work with Swift 3 and have one problem left. Previously, my image caching worked really well, but since the update the `UIImageView`s aren't being populated when the image is fetched.

Here is the code (in the `...cellForItemAt...` function):

```
if let img = imageCache[imageUrl] {
    print("CACHE HIT: \(indexPath)")
    cell.image.image = img
} else {
    print("CACHE MISS: \(indexPath)")
    var imgUrl: = URL(string: imageUrl)
    let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: imgUrl!)
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if(data != nil) {
            print("IMAGE DOWNLOADED: \(imgUrl?.query))")
            let image = UIImage(data: data!) // create the image from the data
            self.imageCache[imageUrl] = image // Store in the cache
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell {
                    print("APPLYING IMAGE TO CELL: \(indexPath)")
                    cell.image.image = image
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print("CELL NOT FOUND: \(indexPath)")
                }
            })
        } 
    }) 
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

As you can see, I've added in some `print`s to find out what is going on. When the view loads, I can see cache misses, and the images loading and the `UIImageView`s being populated for the visible rows, however when I scroll down, the `UIImageView`s are never populated, and the log shows `CELL NOT FOUND: [0, x]` for each indexPath.

If I scroll up again after scrolling down, images are populated from the cache as expected.

The code hasn't changed since the previous version of Swift / iOS / Xcode, and used to work perfectly.

I'm not interested in any 3rd party extensions etc.; I want to understand what is wrong with the code above. Any other improvements/suggestions to the code however are welcome.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than getting the cell via the `cellForItem(at: indexPath)` method, just use the `cell` variable you use to set the image in the cache hit. This will create a strong reference to the cell's image view.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { [weak collectionView] in
    cell.image.image = image
    collectionView?.reloadData()
})
```

*Consider renaming your `UIImageView` to `imageView` rather than `image`.*

Comment: Thanks Callam, that worked perfectly! How does the `[weak self] in` help?

Comment: If you reference self in a closure, this creates a strong reference and this can cause problems sometimes. So the `[weak self]` creates a weak reference that will die quietly.

Comment: Also, replace `[weak self]` with `[weak collectionView]`, then you can use `collectionView?.reloadData()` in your closure

Comment: Worked perfectly - the link was very useful too. Many thanks!