# UICollectionView load image cannot get correct cell swift 3

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uicollectionview, swift3, custom-cell

My UICollectionView is fetching images in `cellForItemAt`. After I upgrade to swift 3, some images are not showing when I scroll very fast. Here is my code in `cellForItemAt`:

```
if (imageNotInCache) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
    if let thumb = imageFromPathAndCacheIt(path) {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          let updateCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell? {
             updateCell.imageView.image = thumb
          }
   }
}
```

The problem is, sometimes I get `updateCell` as nil even it is on the screen (probably because scroll to fast).

I know we can add `reloadData` after adding the image, just like: [Swift 3: Caching images in a collectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561572/swift-3-caching-images-in-a-collectionview), but I don't want to call reload so many times.

Thank you for interested in this question. Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely a compromise between accessing and manually updating the cell view content, and calling `reloadData` on the whole collection view that you could try.

You can use the `func reloadItems(at: [IndexPath])` to ask the `UICollectionView` to reload a single cell if it's on screen.

Presumably, `imageNotInCache` means you're storing `image` in an in-memory cache, so as long as `image` is also accessible by the  `func collectionView(UICollectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath)`, the following should "just work":

```
if (imageNotInCache) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
        if let thumb = imageFromPathAndCacheIt(path) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This can make all images be shown in correct cells . But the thing is now scrolling for the first time becomes jerky... I wonder if there is a way to just get the right cell for updating?

Comment: No worries! Hmm, without knowing more about how your app works, I'm not sure! You might need to use Instruments to see exactly what's blocking the main thread while scrolling. Just in case you're not doing this, simply creating a `UIImage` on a background thread won't decode the image into memory; that'll happen lazily when the image view comes on screen. This can usually cause most scroll view lag. There's a lot of questions on SO on how to explicitly force a `UIImage` to decode ahead of time in the background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904575/decode-images-in-background-thread

Comment: There's also a lot of optimizations you can do in general to improve scroll performance: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.t8tw7ojhp

Comment: Hey thanks for the links, they are very helpful! What I did in my code is that I download all the images beforehand (which a very big), and in `cellForItem` I resize each into a smaller size and put into cache. It might sound weird but that is what i need to do.